# R If statement returns “the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used”

Tags: r, if-statement, stata

I am trying to reproduce results from Stata in R. The specific line that is giving me trouble seems simple.

The line of Stata is
`sum peace_index_score if Africa == 1`

The code I tried in R is

```
if (World$Africa == 1){
    summary(World$peace_index_score)
}
```

This returns the following error message:

```
Warning message in if (World$Africa == 1) {:
“the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used”
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be

```
summary(World$peace_index_score[World$Africa == 1])
```

Comment: `summarize` by default in Stata gives number of non-missing values, mean, SD, minimum and maximum. The OP leaves vague whether they want exactly these results.

Answer (score 0):

Stata automatically applies the test `if Africa == 1` observation by observation (row by row, if you like) given syntax like

```
sum peace_index_score if Africa == 1
```

This is an example of an `if` qualifier.

Stata is like R to the extent that use of the `if` command

```
if Africa == 1 sum peace_index_score
```

is interpreted as

```
if Africa[1] == 1 sum peace_index_score
```

However, that construct in Stata is legal, just rarely what you want, as almost always the `if` command is best used for comparing string or numeric constants (and in fact the above command is doing exactly that). So, it would be legal and idiomatic in Stata to check first for any values of `Africa` that are 1.

```
count if Africa == 1 
if r(N) == 0 sum peace_index if Africa == 1
```